# volume fraction of Ice Ih

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, material-science, ice

we know that the volume fraction of a lattice like HCP is 74%. how can I calculate the volume fraction of a lattice of Ice Ih?

Answer (score 0):

By an internet search for "sphere packing in Ice Ih" I found [this link](https://water.lsbu.ac.uk/water/hexagonal_ice.html) that gives the volume fraction of ice Ih as $\approx 1/3$. You can start from there and dig deeper.

As for *calculating* the volume, construct a geometric model of the crystal with spheres of the maximum possible radius, so that they do not overlap, and calculate the volume of the spheres as a ratio to the volume of the unit lattice.